# Wordpress Admin Bar Not Showing in Front End

Tags: wordpress

I have a **[shayari website]**[1](https://shayaribuzz.com/attitude-shayari/) . The issue with this website is when i am posting some shayari and status i am unable to see the admin bar in front end
I Am using Publisher Theme

Comment: Go to admin > Users > YOUR USERNAME and check the box that says Show Toolbar when viewing site

Comment: Thank You. Didn't expected these silly settings

Comment: No problem, can you accept my answer below pls

Comment: I have checked but still the toolbar is not visible

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin > Users > YOUR USERNAME and check the box that says Show Toolbar when viewing site

Comment: I have checked but still the toolbar is not visible

Comment: Some themes / layout builders hide the admin bar on frontend when using their builder, try switching themes / disabling layout builder to ensure its that. If it is, you can do two things, search for add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' ); in the code and remove it, (not ideal) or try to override in functions using add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' ); or contact support for the theme, they ought to tell you where to look.